# Parsing WebClient data

Tags: c#, regex

So my goal is to download a list of IP Addresses from a website and if its found it, something will be called to. My issue is separating each IP. Here is the current code I tried.

```
public void BlackList()
    {
        try
        {
            WebClient check = new WebClient();
            check.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            string IPS = check.DownloadString("http://SITE.info/blacklist.txt");
            foreach (string s in Regex.Split(IPS))
            {

            }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
     }
```

After this I was going to put them into a list and do if (list.contains IPS...etc but this isn't working. The list looks something like this

```
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex. Just use `String.Split`

```
var blacklist = IPS.Split()
                 .Where(ip => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ip))
                 .Select(ip => IPAddress.Parse(ip))
                 .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're splitting on a separate line, you need to handle both `\r\n` and `\n` style of line breaks (rather than just `Environment.NewLine`).

```
string[] ipList = IPS.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
foreach (string s in ipList)
{
    //do stuff with s
}
```